# Unable to automate the migration process using Task Scheduler and SharePoint cmdlet “MigrateUserAccount”

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, automation, taskscheduler

Unable to automate the migration process using Task Scheduler and SharePoint cmdlet “MigrateUserAccount” getting error “**You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression**”

$spFarm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local
$spFarm.**MigrateUserAccount**("$from\$name", "$to\$name", $false)

When I run the PowerShell script using the “SharePoint 2010 Management Shell” it is running and the output is successful, but when I configured the PowerShell script in Task scheduler the script is running but it throws error like “You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression”

Below screenshot displays that task scheduler is running in high privileges.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHz3u.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk0FX.png)

And this task has been created using the service account who administration access to this servers and added to “db_owners” in sqldatabase aswell.

**Server Architecture**
Web Front End 1
Web Front End 2
Application Server 1
Application Server 2
Database Cluster Node1
Database Cluster Node2

Answer (score 0):

If this is all on one line...

```
$spFarm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local $spFarm.MigrateUserAccount("$from\$name", "$to\$name", $false)
```

...then `$spFarm` will not have been defined when the `MigrateUserAccount` function is invoked.

You'll either need to put a semicolon between the two statements, or put them on separate lines like so:

```
$spFarm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local
$spFarm.MigrateUserAccount("$from\$name", "$to\$name", $false)
```